# OpenLDAP Chain not found

Tags: ubuntu, debian, configuration, openldap

When trying to add a Chain overlay to OpenLDAP 2.4.31 on Ubuntu or Debian, I get a 'overlay "chain" not found' in the syslog.

Furthermore, the schemas required to configure the Chain overlay don't seem to be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chain overlay is loaded via the `back_ldap` module. This is achieved by using:

```
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:///
```

then paste:

```
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: back_ldap
```

After a restart of slapd, the required schemas, such as `olcChainConfig`, will be availablie

A good Chain LDIF example is given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15972631/1554386