# OpenLAP olc (cn=config) and chaining - need assistance

Tags: linux, openldap

So, after a lot of frustrating google-searches it would seem that my Google-fu isn't up to par - the specifics of chaining are no closer to my grasp.

I've gotten part of the way using the answer [here](https://serverfault.com/a/518383), but this doesn't help when I try to add the actual chaining:

`ldapadd -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f chain_conf.ldif`

chain_conf.ldif contains:

```
#dn: olcOverlay={0}chain
#objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
#objectClass: olcChainConfig
#olcOverlay: {0}chain
#olcChainCacheURI: FALSE
#olcChainMaxReferralDepth: 1
#olcChainReturnError: TRUE
#structuralObjectClass: olcChainConfig

dn: olcDatabase={0}config
objectClass: olcLDAPConfig
objectClass: olcChainDatabase
olcDatabase: {0}ldap
olcDbStartTLS: none  starttls=no
olcDbRebindAsUser: FALSE
olcDbChaseReferrals: TRUE
olcDbTFSupport: no
olcDbProxyWhoAmI: FALSE
olcDbProtocolVersion: 3
olcDbSingleConn: FALSE
olcDbCancel: abandon
olcDbUseTemporaryConn: FALSE
olcDbConnectionPoolMax: 16
olcDbSessionTrackingRequest: FALSE
olcDbNoRefs: FALSE
olcDbNoUndefFilter: FALSE
structuralObjectClass: olcLDAPConfig

dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb
objectClass: olcLDAPConfig
objectClass: olcChainDatabase
olcDatabase: {1}ldap
olcDbURI: "ldap://provider.example.com"
olcDbStartTLS: none  starttls=no
olcDbIDAssertBind: mode=self flags=prescriptive,proxy-authz-non-critical bindm
 ethod=simple timeout=0 network-timeout=0 binddn="cn=manager,o=example,c=com”
 credentials="VerySecret" keepalive=0:0:0
olcDbRebindAsUser: FALSE olcDbChaseReferrals: TRUE olcDbTFSupport: no
olcDbProxyWhoAmI: FALSE
olcDbProtocolVersion: 3
olcDbSingleConn: FALSE
olcDbCancel: abandon
olcDbUseTemporaryConn: FALSE
olcDbConnectionPoolMax: 16
olcDbSessionTrackingRequest: FALSE
olcDbNoRefs: FALSE
olcDbNoUndefFilter: FALSE
structuralObjectClass: olcLDAPConfig
```

Attempting to add this gives the following response:

```
root@consumer:~# ldapadd -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f chain_conf.ldif
adding new entry "olcDatabase={0}config"
ldap_add: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
        additional info: no global superior knowledge
```

...and now I'm rather stuck.

The general idea is to have a single main ldap-server which is syncrepl'ed to a few read-only servers which, in turn, provide chaining back to the main server for updates and otherwise provide look-ups.

I've already managed to get syncrepl going and it works fine.

OpenLDAP info:

```
Package: slapd
Version: 2.4.45+dfsg-1ubuntu1
```

OS:

```
Ubuntu 17.10
```

Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: The DN's of the objects you're trying to create look like they're in the wrong part of the tree. AFAIK chaining needs to be configured on the frontend database. The answer you linked to itself links to another question/answer with what looks like the correct objects: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15972631/1554386

Comment: Yes, I've managed to get that far, only now I can't get any further on my own :-(

Comment: The Distinguished Names of your objects don't match what's in the linked answer. You should be creating at least `olcOverlay={0}chain,olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config` and `olcDatabase={0}ldap,olcOverlay={0}chain,olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config`.

Comment: Ehh....ok, could I trouble you for some clarification please?
I think I've stared myself blind at this stuff so my mind seems to be wholely unwilling to even attempt to figure out where to modify the LDIF, and to what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh! - Finally! - Englightenment struck :)

So, firstly it occurred to me that the various
`dn: olcDatabase={N}ldap,olcOverlay={0}chain,olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config` stanzas should match the actual `olcDatabase={N}mdb,cn=config` attributes(?) in `cn=config`, and secondly that cutting&pasting from horrible web pages that use unicode left- and right quotation marks rather than nice ascii double quotes tends to lead to headaches down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your posted LDIF, the Distinguished Names are wrong. It should look something like this:

```
dn: olcOverlay={0}chain,olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcChainConfig
olcOverlay: {0}chain
olcChainCacheURI: FALSE
olcChainMaxReferralDepth: 1
olcChainReturnError: TRUE

dn: olcDatabase={0}ldap,olcOverlay={0}chain,olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
objectClass: olcLDAPConfig
objectClass: olcChainDatabase
olcDatabase: {0}ldap
olcDbStartTLS: none  starttls=no
olcDbRebindAsUser: FALSE
olcDbChaseReferrals: TRUE
olcDbTFSupport: no
olcDbProxyWhoAmI: FALSE
olcDbProtocolVersion: 3
olcDbSingleConn: FALSE
olcDbCancel: abandon
olcDbUseTemporaryConn: FALSE
olcDbConnectionPoolMax: 16
olcDbSessionTrackingRequest: FALSE
olcDbNoRefs: FALSE
olcDbNoUndefFilter: FALSE

dn: olcDatabase={1}ldap,olcOverlay={0}chain,olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
objectClass: olcLDAPConfig
objectClass: olcChainDatabase
olcDatabase: {1}ldap
olcDbURI: "ldap://provider.example.com"
olcDbStartTLS: none  starttls=no
olcDbIDAssertBind: mode=self flags=prescriptive,proxy-authz-non-critical bindmethod=simple timeout=0 network-timeout=0 binddn="cn=manager,o=example,c=com” credentials="VerySecret" keepalive=0:0:0
olcDbRebindAsUser: FALSE
olcDbChaseReferrals: TRUE
olcDbTFSupport: no
olcDbProxyWhoAmI: FALSE
olcDbProtocolVersion: 3
olcDbSingleConn: FALSE
olcDbCancel: abandon
olcDbUseTemporaryConn: FALSE
olcDbConnectionPoolMax: 16
olcDbSessionTrackingRequest: FALSE
olcDbNoRefs: FALSE
olcDbNoUndefFilter: FALSE
```

Note the `dn:` lines are changed.

This assumes you've also loaded the `back_ldap` module as well

Comment: Thanks :)

Yes, I've enabled the back_ldap using the suggestion previously linked.

With your answer I now get a different error though:

    # ldapadd -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f chnsf.ldif
    adding new entry "olcOverlay={0}chain,olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config"
    ldap_add: Constraint violation (19)
        additional info: structuralObjectClass: no user modification allowed

Comment: Delete the `structuralObjectClass:` lines.

Comment: I must seem terribly dense, but I'm still not quite getting it:

first attempt resulted in:
# ldapadd -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f chnsf.ldif
adding new entry "olcOverlay={0}chain,olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config"

adding new entry "olcDatabase=olcDatabase={0}ldap,olcOverlay={0}chain,olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config"
ldap_add: Naming violation (64)
        additional info: value of single-valued naming attribute 'olcDatabase' conflicts with value present in entry

Comment: So I figured it was the olcDatabase=olcDatabase... stuff.

After removing the extra olcDatabase= I get:

adding new entry "olcOverlay={0}chain,olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config"

adding new entry "olcDatabase={0}ldap,olcOverlay={0}chain,olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config"
ldap_add: Object class violation (65)

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault, copy & paste fail. You are correct, the extra `olcDatabase=` needs to be deleted.

Comment: Even with the fixes (deleted `structuralObjectClass`: lines and removed the extra `olcDatabase=` bits, I still get an error:
`# ldapadd -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f chnsf.ldif

adding new entry "olcOverlay={0}chain,olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config"

adding new entry "olcDatabase={0}ldap,olcOverlay={0}chain,olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config"
ldap_add: Object class violation (65)
`

Comment: "Object class violation" means you've either included some attributes that are invalid, or you've not included a required attribute. I would pare back the various `olcDb*` attributes until it works.

Comment: No joy, paring back those bits 'till none remained didn't help. I guess I need to try and find some sufficiently dumbed-down literature to help explain what's needed